# Adjusting for dividend and splits using quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using quantmod to adjust for dividends and splits. It seems to work but I have found the following problem: when adjusting my sma(200,0) historical values are wrong and they correct as the date approaches the current date. Please see the code below.

```
stockData <- new.env() #Make a new environment for quantmod to store data in
symbols = c("IWM","SPY","TLT","TSLA")
nr.of.positions<-3
getSymbols(symbols, src='yahoo',from = "2015-10-01",to = Sys.Date())
for (i in 1:length(symbols)) {
  assign (symbols[i], adjustOHLC(get(symbols[i]), 
               adjust=c("split", "dividend"), 
               use.Adjusted=FALSE,
               symbol.name=symbols[i]))
}

x <- list() 
for (i in 1:length(symbols)) {
  x[[i]] <- get(symbols[i], pos=stockData)  # get data from stockData environment 
  x[[i]]$sma <-SMA(Cl(x[[i]]),10)
  x[[i]]$smalong <-SMA(Cl(x[[i]]),200)
  x[[i]]$adx<-ADX(HLC(x[[i]]),10)
  x[[i]]$rsi <-RSI(Cl(x[[i]]),14)
  x[[i]]$close <-(Cl(x[[i]]))
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195608/quantmod-adjustohlc-function-dividend-adjusted-prices?rq=1) . This will probably answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You're lucky that your code works. Or maybe you're unlucky, since an error would have let you know you did something wrong.

You create a `stockData` environment and the comment says you intended to store the data you pull in it. But you don't specify the `stockData` environment in your call to `getSymbols`, or your calls to `assign` and `get` in the first for loop. So they're all assigning and getting from the global environment.

Your code would be clearer if you avoid using `get` and `assign` within a for loop, and instead used convenience functions `lapply` and `eapply`.

```
stockData <- new.env()
symbols <- c("IWM","SPY","TLT","TSLA")
nr.of.positions <- 3
getSymbols(symbols, from = "2015-10-01", env = stockData)

# loop over objects in an environment with eapply
adj <- eapply(stockData, function(x) {
  symbol <- sub("\\.Close$", "", colnames(Cl(x)))
  adjustOHLC(x, symbol.name=symbol)
})

# loop over list returned by eapply
x <- lapply(adj, function(x) {
  x$sma <- SMA(Cl(x),10)
  x$smalong <- SMA(Cl(x),200)
  x$adx <- ADX(HLC(x),10)
  x$rsi <- RSI(Cl(x),14)
  x$close <- Cl(x)
  x
})
```

You'll notice the results of my code and your code are the same if you run them each in a clean R session. So the reason your code produced "wrong" results is probably because you had other objects in your workspace that were being assigned/accessed by your use of `get` and `assign`.